# How deep does Controls.Clear() clean up?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm using a `TableLayoutPanel` which is dynamically filled with other `TablelayoutPanels`.

Now I'm wondering what happens when I call `TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear` on the dynamically filled `TableLayoutPanel`. Obviously, all the sub-layouts are removed, but how about their children? Are they properly disposed as well or do I need to fear a memory leak?

Should I recursively remove the children of the children before calling `Clear()`?

Comment: If no other object is holding a reference to them the are GC'ed.

Comment: Right, but I'm wondering, the Sub-Tablelayoutpanel holds a reference on its children and the children a reference on its parent. How can i be sure the GC correctly removes them all the time

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) doesn't dispose the controls, leading to a memory leak. From the link:

> Calling the Clear method does not remove control handles from memory.
> You must explicitly call the Dispose method to avoid memory leaks.

Since disposing within a loop messes up the indexing, you can either copy the control collection to another list and perform a `ForEach` loop on them or use a backwards `For` loop.

```
 for (int i = myTableLayoutPanelControls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
    myTableLayoutPanelControls[i].Dispose();
```

Calling `Dispose` will remove the controls from memory (when the GC picks it up). This will also handle the calling of the child control's `Dispose` method.

One catch is if you've got a custom control that implements `IDisposable` or you're overriding the `Dispose` method without calling the `base` method. In your object's `Dispose` method you need to ensure that you've unsubscribed from any events outside your scope. If you don't, that reference will keep your object alive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion in your question. `Clear()` will remove references and objects will be collected by garbage collector.

But, you are also using the word `dispose`. Cleared objects will *not* be disposed in the sense that their `Dispose` method will be called.

Thus, if you are not using those objects anymore, and you want `Dispose` to be called on them, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Okay, so then the question is SHOULD i call dispose on every object I'm not using anymore or is it okayish if i just let the gc remove it. I couldn't think of something that the Dispose method does that is critical for the program just now. Also the question from my previous comment persists, as parent and child reference each other, will the GC collect them?

Comment: Right I did what i should have done before posting the above comment - research. If i get the MSDN right, the Dispose method can be explicitly called and frees up unmanaged resources, what the GC does implicitly using the finalize method (if avail.). However as keyboardP said, Clear doesn't clear all references so i Have to call Dispose explicitly.

Comment: @Xaser `Clear` will clean up all references internal to the controls. It will not affect references that you have in your code. `Finalize` is not guaranteed to be called and that is why you have to call `Dispose` if you want to be certain that all unmanaged resources are cleaned up.