# Dynamically created labels and text boxes not overwriting

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating some labels and text boxes when a combo box changes. I am using a tableFlowContainer with 2 columns and 5 rows. This works fine the first time the selection is changed but if I make another selection the labels and textboxes are not honoring the assigned location but seem to be inserting at 1 element increments. what should be {0,0} is {0,1} and {0,1} goes to {1,0} and so on.

Is there a way of clearing any labels and text boxes before rewritting the?
Here is my code.

```
private void cbPI_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TextBox[] txtBox = new TextBox[5];
    // Label[] lbls = new Label[5];

    for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
    {
        txtBoxs[x] = new TextBox();
        this.txtBoxs[x].Text = "Text"+x;
        this.txtBoxs[x].Name = "txtBoxName"+x;
        this.txtBoxs[x].Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top;
        this.Controls.Add(txtBoxs[x]);

        lbls[x] = new Label();                
        this.lbls[x].Text = "label"+x;
        this.lbls[x].Name = "lblBoxName1"+x;
        this.lbls[x].Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.Controls.Add(lbls[x]);

        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add((lbls[x]), 0, x);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtBoxs[(x)], 1, x);

    }              
}
```

By breaking at the controls the x variable is correct put the placement in the display is not.

Comment: Shouldn't you have to clean the previously added controls before adding the new ones?

Comment: tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()?

Comment: @TaW that was it, so it seems at this point. Thank you. The easiest things I don't think of and the complex just confuses me.:)

Comment: Note however to avoid memory leaks you must also Dispose of them all! [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) : _Calling the Clear method does not remove control handles from memory. You must explicitly call the Dispose method to avoid memory leaks._ Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586347/how-deep-does-controls-clear-clean-up)

Comment: Still doesn't seem logical to me that the label is hard coded to column 1 but the 2nd time through writes in column 2. Clearing before writing again resolves it.

Comment: There probably is some control at (0,0)..